# Where did Wikipedia Pro app disappear to?

Tags: paid-apps

There was this Wikipedia Pro app (paid app; official app by Wikimedia Foundation) coexisitng with the free Wikipedia since long ago app that I purchased. Suddenly, it just seems to vanish from the surface of the earth. Googling hasn't helped me yet.

Anyone with any ideas?

A few bucks is not a big deal but I don't feel like getting fooled.

The sneaky part about his act is that the Wiki Encyclopedia Pro app disappeared from Google search results as well. I understand if some nobody contributes a free app and decide to pull out for whatever reason but big names doing things in secrecy behind their paying customers' back is different.

**Updates**

I've doubled-checked and the app was not made by Wikimedia Foundation so apologies. It appears [Excelentia](http://www.exelentia.co.uk/play.html) did it and their account got shut down by Google. So apparently 9 million users don't matter to Google.

Comment: No idea! Apps come and go depending on support, time, cost and energy, or for other reasons such as developers left, no can do, unless it was open-sourced?

Comment: No @DanHulme, I'm referring to the official app by Wikimedia foundation. The only reason why it's confusing now because that official app is gone

Comment: Was it really an official app by Wikimedia Foundation ? If we talk about this [one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.wikiapps.wikipro), then when I search for the same namespace (`uk.co.wikiapps`), I found [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.wikiapps.hotelfinder). Also, I don't see the Wikimedia Foundation make a Paid app (and not even an app at all).

Comment: Well, they actually made [one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wikipedia) which is free, and they don't sell a "pro" version.

Comment: Yeah, I can't find any mention of a paid version on the [official launch announcement](http://blog.wikimedia.org/2012/01/26/announcing-the-official-wikipedia-android-app/), and they mention there that supplanting the third-party paid apps with a free version was a major reason for developing it, so it seems unlikely that there has ever been a pro version. If it was a third-party app purporting to be from WMF, it may have been pulled by Google.

Answer (score 2):

If an app you've been using isn't offered on the Play Store for some reason (other than being removed for legal reasons, or if it's malware), you can usually still find and install it from your install history.

From the web version of the Play Store, click on Apps, then click on My Apps on the left which should take you to https://play.google.com/apps which should show a list of all of the apps you've ever installed, including ones which have been discontinued, and you can click through to install them:

[image: List of all apps that have been installed from Play Store webpage]

Alternatively you can do the same thing on your phone, open the Play Store app, go to My Apps, and then change from the "Installed" tab to the "All" tab and scroll down until you find your app (I think they're listed in the order that you first installed them):

[image: List of all apps that have been installed from Play Store app]

*(I'd advise using the web page, as you can normally find what you're after quicker than when doing a lot of scrolling down in the app)*

Comment: Thanks @GAThrawn. 1) I already tried viewing my apps on Google Play website but the Wikipedia Pro app is not there anymore! 2) I've just tried the mobile view as you suggested but it's not there either. The app you mentioned as example deserve respect then since it quits decently